# PHP check SSL prevent php warning

Tags: php, ssl

I am using the PHP code below to load the certificate properties of an SSL website:

```
$dnsname        = 'www.google.com';
$dnsport        = 443;
$stream     = stream_context_create (array("ssl" => array("capture_peer_cert" => true)));
$url        = stream_socket_client("ssl://".$dnsname.":".$dnsport, $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $stream);
$content    = stream_context_get_params($url);
```

This all works fine when SSL is working OK. But in case no SSL connection can be opened the script results in a PHP warning:

> stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://www.google.nl:443 (Kan geen verbinding maken omdat de doelcomputer de verbinding actief heeft geweigerd.
>   ) in C:\inetpub\monitor\autotask\checkssl.php on line 44

How to prevent the warning? I need a "if" but don't know what to check for.. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppress the warning using the [`@`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) operator and check the outcome yourself based on the [return value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php#refsect1-function.stream-socket-client-returnvalues):

```
$socket = @stream_socket_client(...);
if ($socket === false) {
    die("Socket error: $errstr");
}
```