# Check SSL connection with PHP: intercept warnings or anyway manually handle various scenarios

Tags: php, security, ssl, curl, https

I want to get the details of digital certificate of a domain, if the digital certificate exists.

I want to build something like the [Google Chrome security indicator](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95617?p=ui_security_indicator&rd=1).

To get the details of the digital certificate, I use this code:

```
    $cacert = $this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/../src/AppBundle/Resources/public/security/cacert.pem';

    $host = 'www.mywebsite.it';

    $contextOptions = [
        'http' => [
            'ignore_errors' => true
        ],
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'cafile' => $cacert,
            //'peer_name' => $host,
            'ciphers' => 'HIGH',
            'disable_compression' => true,
            'capture_peer_cert' => true,
            'capture_peer_cert_chain' => true
        ],
    ];

    $context = stream_context_create($contextOptions);

    $domain = preg_replace('/(http:\/\/)|(https:\/\/)/', '', $host);
    $socket = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://' . $domain . ':443',
        $errno,
        $errstr,
        30,
        STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,
        $context
        );

    if (!$socket) {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    }

    $params = stream_context_get_params($socket);

    $cert_resource = $params['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate'];
    $cert = openssl_x509_parse($cert_resource);

    dump($cert);die;
```

This code was taken from [here](https://github.com/jonnybarnes/guzzle-aia/blob/master/src/AIASubscriber.php#L26-L47).

What I'd like to achieve is a script that can behave like the Google Chrome SSL certificate Checker, so I'd like to know if a website is secure or not and, if yes, how much it is. Details about Google Chrome security indicators can be found [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95617?p=ui_security_indicator&rd=1).

**THE PROBLEMS/QUESTIONS**

1) `stream_socket_client()` raises some `Warning`s if problems happen instead of using `\Exception`s. So, how can I intercept `Warning`s to understand what is happening?
Is the custom error handler the only solution as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440170/php-check-ssl-prevent-php-warning), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822527/prevent-error-warnings-if-connection-could-not-be-established), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241751/1399706)?

As you can see from the code above, I've also set the `http` `ignore_errors` property to `false`, but this seems not working (see point number 2, the following). This possible solution was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21976746/1399706).

2) My domain hasn't a digital certificate, but my server has one, so, when I try to get the certificate, I get the following error:

> Warning: stream_socket_client(): Peer certificate
>   CN='ssl.my.server.com' did not match expected
>   CN='www.mydomain.it'

So, I cannot get the certificate details because the connection stops before I get them. How can I get anyway the details of the certificate? Is this connection secure or not? Is the difference with a green Chrome bar only the fact that the certificate is for a domain different than the one called? But this connection is secure or not?

3) I've tried to get the certificate details of a domain without a certificate (also the server hasn't one) and I get this warning:

> Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://www.non-secure-domain.com:443 (Operation timed out)

Is this error sufficient to say the domain hasn't a digital certificate at all? Which is the difference between this error and the one I get at the point 2?

4) The last question: as it is possible to connect to a remote host also via `cURL`, should have I to use `cURL` or it sufficient `stream_socket_client()`? Which is the difference between the two for my use case (getting the digital certificate details)?

Thank you for your advices :)